# Substituting a function into a symbolic derivative term giving summations

Tags: replacement

Suppose I have terms which are symbolic derivatives of an undefined function:

```
f'[x]
(* Derivative[1][f][x] *)
```

If I later find out that this function can be described better by another function such as:

$$
f(x) = x^4 F(x)
$$

I would want to be able to make the following substitution (left abstracted in case there were more terms):

```
func[x] = x^4 F[x]^4

f'[x] /. Derivative[a_][f][x] -> D[func[x], {x, a}]

(* 
Inactive[Sum][x^(4 - K[1])*Binomial[1, K[1]]*
     D[F[x]^4, {x, 1 - K[1]}]*FactorialPower[4, K[1]], 
   {K[1], 0, 1}]
*)
```

but we see that this gives a very strange term that includes a summation over a variable $K(1)$. This feels like a very strange behaviour that I can't make sense of expecially considering the following behaviour:

```
D[func[x], {x, 1}]
(* 4 x^3 F[x]^4 + 4 x^4 F[x]^3 Derivative[1][F][x] *)
```

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Try it with :> instead of ->  in the replacement rule. The indefinite a-th derivative is evaluated and then the value of a is substituted in your code

Comment: I would use a pure function: `f'[x] /. f -> Function[#^4 F[#]^4]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 that worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the OP's code, we get, as shown in the OP,

```
func[x] = x^4 F[x]^4;
f'[x] /. Derivative[a_][f][x] -> D[func[x], {x, a}]

(* 
Inactive[Sum][x^(4 - K[1])*Binomial[1, K[1]]*
     D[F[x]^4, {x, 1 - K[1]}]*FactorialPower[4, K[1]], 
   {K[1], 0, 1}]
*)
```

where the output is the result of replacing `a` by `1` in

```
D[func[x], {x, a}]
(*
Inactive[Sum][x^(4 - K[1]) * Binomial[a, K[1]] *
     D[F[x]^4, {x, a - K[1]}] * FactorialPower[4, K[1]],
   {K[1], 0, a}]
*)
```

which is a rule from calculus (maybe due to Leibniz, but I forget at the moment).

Here are several fixes:

*Activate the sum:*

```
f'[x] /. Derivative[a_][f][x] -> D[func[x], {x, a}] // Activate
```

*Use `RuleDelayed`,* which will hold the derivative `D[]` from being evaluated until `a` has been replaced:

```
f'[x] /. Derivative[a_][f][x] :> D[func[x], {x, a}]
```

*Carl Woll's suggestion,* a variation on:

```
f'[x] /. f -> Function[x, Evaluate@func[x]]
```

If we redefine `func` as a proper function, there are more:

```
ClearAll[func];
func[x_] := x^4 F[x]^4;  (* the key is x_ instead of x;
                            for := vs. = see below  *)
f'[x] /. f -> func         (* best way, overall? *)
f'[x] /. f -> (func[#] &)  (* a somewhat pointless embellishment
                              of f -> func  *)
```

All yield:

```
(*  4 x^3 F[x]^4 + 4 x^4 F[x]^3 Derivative[1][F][x]  *)
```

On defining functions and `SetDelayed` (`:=`) versus `Set` (`=`), see points #6 and #9 and the links contained therein of this answer:

- [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395)

Comment: One reason I like using the replacement for `f` is when the expression is `f'[x] + f[x]`